# Identical SSDs on same port: Why is one SATA/600 and the other SATA/150?

Tags: ssd, sata, hotswapping, transfer-rate

## Overview

Over the course of a few months I purchased two of the same SSD from different stores (both *960GB SandDisk SSD PLUS*, same firmware(Z33110RL) - just waited for them to be on sale) with the intention of combining them in RAID0.

When the second drive arrived, I benchmarked both to make sure everything was working.

[image]

For convenience, I used a drivebay (like in the image above) on a SATA port configured for hot swapping in the BIOS to test the two drives using [CrystalDiskMark](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskMark/index-e.html). I used the same sata port, simply swapping one for the other.

[image]

I noticed that one of the drives (the one I had just purchased, and so had not used yet) was performing *drastically* worse than the other, despite being on the same motherboard(*GA-Z97M-D3H*), on the same SATA connection, and the same model(*960GB SandDisk SSD PLUS*) with the same firmware(*Z33110RL*).

---

## Different Transfer Mode

I tried forcing Trim, reformatting again, copying some files to it, etc. but the results were consistent, and I tried swapping the drives back and forth several times; The results never changed, and the new drive was consistently about 1/4 of the speed of the other one on Sequential tests.

Checking [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) to see if there were any discrepencies, I noticed that the slow drive was showing its Transfer Mode as `SATA/150 | SATA/600`, meaning that it was using `SATA/150` but supported `SATA/600`, while the other drive was showing `SATA/600 | SATA/600`.

The slow drive:

[image]

The fast drive:

[image]

Swapping the two drives will consistently yield this behaviour, the newer one (serial number ending in *193*) is always using `SATA/150`, while the other one (serial number ending in *876*) is always using `SATA/600`.

---

## Question

What would cause this behavior? What determines the selected 'Transfer Mode' for the drive?

The drives are -identical-, both formatted to NTFS, and are being tested on the exact same motherboard/port/etc.

I have used this hot-swap bay with dozens of drives before, and none have ever acted up like this.

Comment: Could it be as simple as a bad or dirty contact (SATA)?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, had a similar problem, the answer turned out to be that the manufacturer had mislabeled the drive. It was a "Crucial" disk and they replaced it, after I convinced them that this was the problem. You might check that!